# my app dont work with self signed SSL in android < 5

Tags: android, ssl

I use retrofit2:

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

My site ssl is self-signed ssl : https://pccloob.ir.
How can I solve this problem:

In android 4.0 there no errors in logcat or run but in android 4.4 - HandShake error.

I tried all the suggestions from stackoverflow and the Internet, but nothing works.

Comment: Please provide the related logcat or stacktrace.

Comment: my ssl is not support tls v1.0 and tls v1.1 based on :https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pccloob.ir&latest only support tls v 1.2 .
and tls v1.2 is supported android >= 4.4.2
i want use this ssl in android < 4.4.2.....

Comment: I see a Let's Encrypt SSL cert not a self-signed one...

Comment: so, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates from [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org) are compatible with Android `>= v2.3.6`.

the trick is the `SSL/TLS` protocol configuration of the virtual host:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

the `certbot` might not configure these ciphers by default, because of:

- [POODLE](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/poodle-vulnerability-in-ssl-30/) (Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption), affects some TLS 1.0 & 1.1.
- [BEAST](https://docs.secureauth.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14778519) (Browser Exploit Against SSL/TLS), affects all TLS 1.0.

so you have the choice, in between backwards compatibility & offering insecure ciphers.

[ssllabs.com](https://:ssllabs.com) might report an `F` instead of an `A`, when the server is vulnerable.

Comment: thanks , i contact with my hosting company but they said : we cant enable it.
is there a way to solve this problem in my app?